# Pausing flash animation while a dialog box appears

Tags: flash, dialog, box

I have a fairly long flash animation, with various different symbols and motion tweens etc.
My goal is to pause this animation at several different times, while a dialog box appears, and then resume the animation again. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using all timeline based animation and different symbols have different timelines, then it's a bit more tricky than if you are using scripts for your animation (greensock or the like) which provide killAll functions.

If you are using all timeline animations and different symbols have different timeline animations, then you could set a global enterframe function that all symbols listen for and if the pause condition is met, it sets a variable that stops the timelines, starting them where they left off when the pause condition is over. I'd be happy to help you resolve this if you could give more info, and perhaps provide a source file to look at.